# webapp javascript function in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

im not english user but im trying to right write. plz get this

i want

A== Google App script .gs

```
var result = solvethis(1,3);
Logger.Log(result) // 4
```

B== webapp javascript .html

```
<script>
    function solvethis(a,b){

    return a+b
    }
</script>
```

why i do this want.

i want use some data Library with make javascript
=> alasql.js

but in .gs -> alasql.js is not work.

so i have to use html.

i dont know a lot but i know dget.

---

1===.gs

```
function dget(e){
 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
}
alasql(select * )
```

2===.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alasql@0.5"></script>
```

---------------- => it not work.

i do not want webapp page directly open.
but i want js Library in .gs

how can i do this?

Comment: Make sure `solveThis` is defined before it is used in the google script.

Comment: evolutionxbox // but how defined before? These are two separate files.

Comment: They are used in the same HTML file, correct?

Comment: evolutionxbox // No, I want to use the JavaScript library in the .gs file.
In conclusion, the function is html JavaScript.
I want to use that function in the .gs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** invoke client side functions from the server, with the sole exception of the success or failure handler specified for a client-side-initiated call to a server function. Note that your server-side code **cannot** know which client side function was registered as the response handler, or even if there was one registered at all.

So no, you can't "just" call a .html-defined function from your .gs files.

Please review the [HTMLService guide and API reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

```
// client.html (you write the UI and other stuff for the sidebar or modal or webapp page)
function calledByServer(serverOutput) {
  console.log({ serverOutput }); // or whatever you want to do with the response
}
function doServer(...argsArray) { //invoke somehow, e.g. a client-side click handler
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(calledByServer)
    .ServerSideFunctionName(argsArray);
}

// Code.gs
function ServerSideFunctionName(foo) {
  console.log(foo); // Stackdriver logging, since Logger is instance specific
  // Do something with foo
  return someValueToSendToClient;
}
```

If you want to have that library available, you **must** build and use a UI to work with it, in purely client-side code.